# serious error while trying to mount partition xxx ignore skip mounting manual recovery

Tags: 11.10, boot, mount, ntfs, fstab

Yesterday I upgraded from Natty to Oneiric and I got a "Serious error while trying to mount partition /media/xxx. It is an NTFS partition. I chose Skip, I checked the partition with disk utility while says "File system is NOT clean". I booted in Windows and checked the partition which did not find any errors.

Next, I did a backup, I reformatted the partition and recopied all my files, edited FSTAB with the new UUID. Same error on boot. Again Windows says there are not problems.

Is this a problem with NTFS handling in Oneiric? I'm tempted to remove partition checking from Fstab since it seems I'm getting false warnings.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error until I changed the corresponding line in fstab to the following:

```
UUID=59B1C23E4CFCC9F3                 /mnt/shared     ntfs-3g defaults        0       0
```

See the answers to [the following questions](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+question/175474) for more details.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Deciding_which_partitions_to_mount

Answer (score 1):

ntfs-3g does not contain the needed executable to check the fs, so fsck will report that as an error on start-up. The solution can be found in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/86088. 
Create two symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs
sudo ln -s /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3g
```

Answer (score 0):

By changing the 6th field you are omitting the disk check on the drive.
Still don't know why yet. The straight mount works fine when you skip the mount during logon and mount -a when logged on
Peter

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.