# fsck can't find fsck.ntfs

Tags: ntfs, fsck

On several machines that I've upgraded from Natty to Oneiric, I get an error every boot (one for every NTFS partition):

```
Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /windows/c.

Press I to ignore, S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery
```

Following the suggestion in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/58311/13398), I ran `fsck` from the manual recovery shell. I got this output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.19.1
fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found
fsck: Error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sda1
```

I can't find fsck.ntfs, and `command-not-found` doesn't help either. **How can I make this error go away?**

By the way, I've tried booting into Windows (XP) several times, thinking that Windows would repair the filesystems. But apparently Windows thinks the filesysystems are just fine. And it's odd that *all* NTFS filesystems are affected.

Also, I can work around this problem by dropping to a recovery shell and issuing `mount -a`, but for my coworkers' sakes I need unattended boot.

Comment: I can't find `fsck.ntfs` I think you should go with `ntfsck` or `ntfsfix` for ntfs partitions, AFAIK `fsck` is mainly used for ext partition.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`fsck.ntfs` is usually only a link to `ntfsfix` which is an utility from the package `ntfsprogs` that is already available with a standard installation of Ubuntu.

You can make a simbolic link between fsck.ntfs and ntfsfix to solve this permanently:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3g
```

Keep in mind that this utility came from a reverse engineering process and are not the best option to manage your filesystem, the NTFS filesystem does not belong to the GNU/linux world.

Comment: Thanks. I set up the symlinks (which should have been made already) and the problem is solved. The only question that remains is: Why was the symlink missing in the first place? fsck apparently runs on boot. Therefore, it is a bug if it tries to check a filesystem that it can't handle. The partition was--and has been--perfectly fine. Apparently this was just a routine check that was failing.

Comment: It is funny I trust a community reversed engineered tool a lot more than the official Microsoft tool which destroyed my perfectly working NTFS partitions before :)

Comment: Doesn't work to me. Ubuntu 12.04.3

Comment: You can count more on Linux-based tools to recover your Windows installation and data than the Windows-based tools. Also I experienced that Linux lets you do things such as putting question marks in your filenames; this is officially permitted by NTFS standards but here's the joke: the Windows driver doesn't support it!

I would like to point at dedicated "Linux-based Rescue / Repair Live-CDs" (or USB) such as SystemRescueCD.

Comment: The answer should be: http://askubuntu.com/a/292889/126984

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 lacks the ntfsprogs package.

Comment: In the latest Ubuntu you should install `ntfs-3g` package and use `ntfsfix` utility.

Answer (score 21):

I think it could be noted for some people that `ntfsfix` gets installed into `/bin/` instead of `/usr/bin`. So

```
sudo ln -nsf /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs
sudo ln -nsf /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3g
```

If you have already created the symlink from `/usr/bin/`

```
sudo rm -f /sbin/fsck.ntfs
sudo rm -f /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3g
```

And then create the symlinks again.

Comment: upvoted because a) downvoter left no comment explaining downvote, which would be courteous at least, and b) just had to 'locate ntfsfix' to find mine at /bin/ntfsfix, so it seems relevant at least.

Comment: I would suggest adding this as a comment to Micro's answer, rather than as a standalone answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer for later versions of ubuntu like 13.04

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04!

Answer (score 6):

If you have an NTFS partition automatically mounted at startup, the only reason could be you have manually or through some tool added it to `/etc/fstab` (not taking into account WUBI).

If the system tries to check the partition at startup it means that in the corresponding line in `/etc/fstab` there is a sixth field and its value is `1` or `2`.

`ntfsfix` is not linked by default to `fsck.ntfs`, and it only provides limited check capabilities, as explained in the man page:

> ntfsfix  is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems.  ntfsfix is
>      NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some  fundamental  NTFS
>      inconsistencies,  resets  the  NTFS  journal file and schedules an NTFS
>      consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

The common solution is not to create the symlink, but to remove or set to `0` the sixth field in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Actually, that's not exactly accurate. During installation, existing NTFS partitions get automatically added to fstab without any manual editing of fstab. So, they should get added in a sane way. I don't care whether they get checked or not. I just don't want unnecessary errors messages showing up at boot when in reality there is no error.

Comment: Never seen this behavior in older Ubuntu releases, when I had ntfs partitions. I suppose is a new features, now that I do not use ntfs anymore. Btw, you did not say if there was the non-zero number in fstab.

Comment: This might explain the problem: On the machine in question, there is indeed a nonzero number in fstab. On another machine, I formerly had this same problem, but it went away after I did a reinstall to solve a different issue. The new fstab has the sixth field set to zero. So, apparently the defaults changed between Natty and Oneiric and the upgrade didn't make any conversions.

Comment: Me thinks that the "pass" argument is just in what order the partitions should be auto mounted, so this seems to be new in Oneiric. I just upgraded recently and I have had pass=3 set on my ntfs partitions, and I never had any problem until the first boot in oneiric. It got stuck on some stupid promt hidden among some irrelevant error messages. Not cool for a server to wait for a  keypress during boot.

Answer (score 5):

Micro's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/86088/235) worked for me, however my 11.10 (upgraded from 11.04) did not have ntfsprogs.  '`sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`' solved that, then the link suggestion worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a missing symbolic link, to either `/usr/bin/ntfsfix` or `/bin/ntfsfix`. You can make the needed link(s) with:

```
sudo ln -s $(which ntfsfix) /sbin/fsck.ntfs
sudo ln -s $(which ntfsfix) /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3
```

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on April 13th, 2015

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem after I accidentally installed `ntfsprogs`. I think there is bug in dependencies because after installation of `ntfsprogs` all NTFS drives started mounting read-only.

When I turned back `ntfs-3g`, `fsck.ntfs` disappeared.

SO:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ntfs-3g
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ntfsprogs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

BUT:

```
apt-cache showpkg ntfs-3g
Package: ntfs-3g
Versions: 
1:2011.4.12AR.4-2ubuntu3 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
...
Provides: 
1:2011.4.12AR.4-2ubuntu3 - ntfsprogs
```

I'm not sure what should be the right behavior there but be aware of it.

Comment: I think so my usb is no useful furthermore please confirm :ntfsfix /dev/sdc1 Mounting volume... The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). FAILED Attempting to correct errors... Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr... Reading $MFT... OK Reading $MFTMirr... OK Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully. Setting required flags on partition... OK Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK Failed to sync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error Checking the alternate boot sector... OK

Comment: NTFS volume version is 3.1. NTFS partition /dev/sdc1 was processed successfully. Failed to sync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error Failed to unmount partition

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu 14.04 package is not available as of Jan 2015

1. `sudo ln -s /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs`
2. `sudo ln -s /bin/ntfsfix /sbin/fsck.ntfs-3g`
3. `sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs`

   ```
   Package ntfsprogs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
   is only available from another source
   E: Package 'ntfsprogs' has no installation candidate
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man fsck
```

> fsck - check and repair a Linux filesystem

To repair a broken NTFS system on GNU / Linux you could use ntfsfix which is part of [ntfs-3g](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G) as following:

```
$ ntfsfix /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: -1: This answer is unrelated to the question.

Comment: @ScottSeverance /me being down voted for not ignoring the tools application as stated in their manual -- only in Ubuntu forums haha

Comment: The question was about `fsck.ntfs` not being found at boot. Obviously, reporting the man page of irrelevant, since `fsck` wasn't being invoked manually. In addition, the situation wouldn't have arisen in the first place except for the fact that at one time `fsck.ntfs` *did* exist on a default Ubuntu install.

Comment: @ScottSeverance Thanks for stating that your thread is outdated!

Comment: It's quite possible that this question is outdated (though I can't be bothered to check so I can say for certain). However, that isn't the reason I down voted this answer. Even if it had been posted before my issue was solved, it doesn't even begin to address the question I asked. I asked about an error that appeared during boot and interrupted the boot process. The error indicated that the system was looking for `fsck.ntfs`, which didn't exist on the system. How exactly could an explanation of which tool is appropriate for fixing disk errors help me resolve my boot error?

Comment: @ScottSeverance it helps you preserve the system hierarchy by adapting to its standards. If everyone links everything everywhere without understanding the utility of each component the system becomes a mess and one does not learn a proper way that has been defined by generations of developers. It would be fair to say that misleading new users by referring to past methods is unjustified. I bring an answer which obeys to today standards across the majority of GNU / Linux distributions.

Comment: # ntfsfix /dev/sdc1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdc1 was processed successfully.
Failed to sync device /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
Failed to unmount partition
root@ubuntu-spark:/home/spark# fdisk /dev/sdc

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: Read-only file system

Answer (score 0):

Try to force remapping of damaged sectors using this script:
https://techoverflow.net/blog/2015/01/07/fixing-bad-blocks-on-hdds-using-fixhdd.py/

mirror: https://github.com/unxed/fixhdd

This script looks into system log for i/o errors every 5 seconds and writes zeroes to faulty sectors to force hdd controller to remap them.
Usage sample:
sudo fixhdd.py --loop /dev/sda

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.