# Hard Drive Dying

Tags: hard-drive, automount, diagnostic

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 on my older desktop. Sometimes when booting up, I get a message that "/" or "/tmp" could not be mounted, or else a disk error was detected and a disk check will start executing. Suspect that my old hard drive is beginning to fail. Is there a diagnostic that will indicate if it is the hard drive or the controller that is beginning to fail?

Comment: What part of the "/" or "/tmp" or "disk error" do you think a diagnostic didn't just happen?  Buy another hardrive and reload

Comment: take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/561865/what-is-the-best-way-to-scan-a-hard-drive-check-health-in-ubuntu

Comment: Answer is probably not but if there were one would you just replace the bad platter? Or just the controller? Interesting question but suffers from XY problem, you need a new drive :)

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect that your hard drive might be dying, I suggest running some kind of diagnostic software - but only after backing up all of your data! Sometimes this is built into the computer, and can be run by either navigating to the Diagnostic tab in BIOS,

[image]

or there will be a key designated for this purpose, which you will have to press at startup.

[image]

For a more in-depth diagnosis, I personally recommend downloading the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html), which includes ViVARD - a low-level HDD diagnostic software, which runs on top of DOS. This is a bootable image which you will have to burn to a CD, or write to a USB flash drive.