# Have to reinstall ubuntu 16.04 repeatedly

Tags: boot, reinstall

My screen only will go to this after it seem to freeze up, then on restart I got a black screen with this message:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu -vg-root contains a file system with errors, check forced
/dev/mapper/ubuntu - -vg -root
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found
```

I had to reinstall Ubuntu from CD twice this week. Before going black it seemed to freeze up often. Only thing I did recently was install a new graphics card; it is a supported card.

Comment: What will the screen go to before it freezes up? Also this sounds like a bug, when it's working again please use `ubuntu-bug` in Terminal and follow the wizard, when it loads the Launchpad webpage please explain the problem as clearly as possible and give as much information as possible so the developers have a chance of fixing it :)

Comment: @Ads20000 how do you figure that this is a Ubuntu bug?

Comment: @heynnema if Ubuntu isn't 'just working' then it's probably a bug. We're not Arch, Ubuntu should work without problem (unless you've done something silly with root).

Comment: @Ads20000 **that's just wrong**. Without asking **any** further questions you've figured it's a Ubuntu bug? I don't think that even the developers have that skill. It sounds more like a hard disk problem to me. I've answered the question with a process that will help determine if that's a good educated diagnosis or not. I'm waiting for the OP to reply.

Comment: Sorry, I usually respond thinking it's a bug so it can go to Launchpad and get fixed if it is a bug. A lot of questions go unanswered and I don't want people feeling that no-one cares about their issue. Perhaps this is the wrong motive however. But often it is a bug because the system isn't working as people expect, and it should. Maybe I should change my workflow so I only refer people to Launchpad on older unanswered questions rather than immediately, but I just want to help and often I don't have a solution to a problem :(

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got a hard disk problem. The first thing is to perform a file system check...

- boot to the GRUB menu (where you select which OS to start)
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- *you can ignore errors about the time/date/superblock*
- repeat the fsck command if there were other errors
- type `reboot`

Answer (score 0):

I will add to heynnema's comment by adding that you would want to do some other hardware diagnostics as well. Really, what you want to do is rule out hardware problems as much as possible at this point. Once you determined that it isn't an issue there then you can focus on a potential software problem.

1.) Make sure your CD media is working correctly by selecting the 'Check CD for defects (very dated images on [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck), but you get the idea). My recommendation would be to switch to using USB sticks. Besides being faster, you won't worry about scratching them.

2.) Check your HDD for errors with the 'Disks' utility that comes with Ubuntu. The Live-CD has it already available.

[image]

Check the 'Assessment' first, which is a simple output of the last SMART values check. You may want to run a new check by pressing the options button in the top right and selecting "Smart DATA & Self test".

This will give you an initial indication of potential trouble. But SMART data isn't always indicative of all issues. You may also have to do a [surface scan of the drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/561865/what-is-the-best-way-to-scan-a-hard-drive-check-health-in-ubuntu).

3.) Check your memory for issues. Memory errors can creep up on working systems at any time. Choose the 'Memory Test' option on the boot selection of the Live CD to perform a memory test. This will take a couple hours (depending on the amount of RAM you have).

Once you have made sure it's not a hardware issue, you can move over to check for software/driver issues.