# a specific USB disk isn't mounted automatically

Tags: 14.04, usb, mount, ntfs, automatic

Generally all usb devices mount automatically. Only this device when I connect it I don't see it. However I could mount it with the `mount` command: `sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt` and I see its contents. But why does it not mount automatically?

---

Here's some information about it:

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 8004 MB, 8004304896 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 973 cylinders, total 15633408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x17362d1c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1    15633407     7816703+  ee  GPT
```

Screenshot with some information:

[image: ScreenShot]

It contains a bootable windows7 64bit installer.

btw Cairo dock detects it!

[image: cairo dock scrnsht]

[image: requested screenshot]

output of `dmesg`: ( command used: `watch -n 0.1 "dmesg | tail -n $((LINES-6))"` )

```
[151598.476345] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
[151598.492869] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5567
[151598.492871] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[151598.492872] usb 3-7: Product: Cruzer Blade
[151598.492873] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[151598.492874] usb 3-7: SerialNumber: 4C530199941217122025
[151598.493304] usb-storage 3-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[151598.493419] scsi17 : usb-storage 3-7:1.0
[151599.494750] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer Blade     1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[151599.495090] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[151599.496040] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdd] 15633408 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 GB/7.45 GiB)
[151599.497078] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[151599.497081] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[151599.497312] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[151599.513785]  sdd: sdd1
[151599.515872] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto no they're GPT too. `fdisk` shows the "GPT detected" part on my other drives too. Does GPT relate to the issue?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto it says "ask what to do". more attempts are welcome XD

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I changed it but no luck, still  not automounting. Edited in the output of dmesg. I used a different command because the `-n` needed a number of lines

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I wanted to write `-n 30` and forgot the number. :) I am still not sure why it doesn't work. It says `xhci_hcd`: are other (auto-mounting) drives also "extra high capacity" (`xhc`)?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto just tried another usb stick and looked at dmesg and I see the `using xhci_hcd` part, and it auto-mounts fine. generally all disks I connect work fine. Even this one we're talking about here. It used to auto-mount till I put on it that bootable win7. I'll reformat it but I want to know why on earth is it not auto-mounting XD

Comment: Sorry to ask so many clarifications, but they surely help with debugging the issue. BTW I am going to delete a few of my previous comments from here because they are obsolete. Could you run a `fsck` on the problematic partition?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto it's totally okay. I'm not formatting it just to debug :D

Comment: It gives me some weird error. `fsck: fsck.ntfs: not found`
`fsck: error 2 while executing fsck.ntfs for /dev/sdc1`

Comment: ...so apparently I should use `ntfsfix` which I did and the output is fine: `Mounting volume... OK`
`Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.`
`Checking the alternate boot sector... OK`
`NTFS volume version is 3.1.`
`NTFS partition /dev/sdc1 was processed successfully.`

Comment: «so apparently I should use ntfsfix» Not really. That means you don't have the `fsck.ntfs` tool installed. Install it and try again. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto but I saw several link that say that `fsck.ntfs` is a link to `ntfsfix`. see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86086/fsck-cant-find-fsck-ntfs) for example. I tried searching for "fsck.ntfs" as it is but I couldn't find it. I also tried `sudo apt-get install fsck.ntfs`

Comment: Gosh, you are right. That is bad because `ntfsfix` does basically nothing. I am running out of ideas.