# How to have Ubuntu read the file in windows hard drive which became RAW?

Tags: hard-drive, live-cd

I have a 2TB USB Windows hard drive which suddenly became RAW.
The hard drive contains only HD movies, mkv files. There's no OS there.

From [this link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/313627-read-a-raw-format-hard-drive-on-a-windows-machine) and [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/), it seems I may get the chance to recover the data using Ubuntu Live CD.
So I download the Ubuntu iso file and burn it to a blank DVD.

After I boot from the Live CD, I use the "Try Ubuntu" option, but the raw drive is not listed in "Files" directory as seen below :
[image]

---

After playing around what is inside the Ubuntu desktop, I found a "Disks" icon, so I double click it and it show the raw drive (orange highlighted) :
[image].

---

Based from reading in the internet, I open the terminal window and type `sudo fdisk -l`, and the result is below :
[image]
with red text *"partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary"* at the bottom.

---

The CrystalDisk information result show like below: 
[image]

---

I need help from the experts if there is a way to have Ubuntu read the raw hard drive and explore it so I can copy it to another hard drive.

Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

PS : Sorry I forgot to mention that I've tried TestDisk from Windows 10. But it seems there is something wrong with the drive which cause it became so hot after about 3 hours of Deeper Search. So I stop it. I post this "hot" problem in the [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/questions/1602139/is-it-normal-the-2tb-usb-hard-drive-become-so-hot-during-the-testdisk-deeper-se?noredirect=1#comment2442030_1602139).

Comment: What file system does the volume use?

Comment: RAW means it lost its format. And it is both in partition table which shows NTFS, but also in the partition boot sector (BS or PBR). NTFS has a backup BS that you may recover. But that it now shows it starts at sector 2 may be a separate issue. A 4K drive should start at sector 2048, normally, but at least some sector divisible by 8. Did start sector also get changed.

Comment: @Nmath, too bad - I don't know what file system the hard drive use. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @oldfred, oh I see. So actually the BootStart should start at 2048 normally. But mine show is start at 2. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Do you have packages `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` installed? I ask for the file system type because you might need additional packages.  exFAT file systems should still show up as such, but its worth a shot to verify that your system has exFAT capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk has been marked as "raw" because the filesystem was corrupted for some reason (not ejecting, not shutting down, bad luck, whatever). You can likely repair the disk with a command line tool known as `fsck`. You may want to look at [this U&L post](https://superuser.com/questions/233700/fsck-an-ntfs-drive-in-linux#233702), as well as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86086/fsck-cant-find-fsck-ntfs). You're going to want to boot into the live CD / USB drive and run `fsck` from a terminal. From [man fsck](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck):

> fsck [-sAVRTMNP] [-C [fd]] [-t fstype] [filesys...] [--] [fs-specific-options]

What this means is you need to find the identifier of your disk (in your screenshot /dev/sda1, though you should check again with `sudo fdisk -l` to be sure, especially after reboots), and run the command:

> sudo fsck -t NTFS  /dev/sda1

(replace NTFS with FAT32 if that was the format of the drive). If all goes well (which it may not), you should be able to [mount the disk manually](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mounting-hard-disks-partitions-using-linux-command-line/) or reboot your computer and access the drive. If `fsck` has errors, edit your answer to include them as well.

Comment: Hi Pixelated Fish, thank you for your answer. The problem is I don't know the format of the drive. I bought the drive which already contains the mkv files. My bad, I never check what is the format of the drive. From the photo I post, it say "Partition Type : HPFS/NTFS/exFAT", so I don't know which one should I write in sudo fsck -t ??? /dev/whatever-theRawdisk-id-show-in-ubuntu. Will it be a disaster if I try it each of them ?(HPFS, NTFS, exFAT). Thank you once again

Comment: BTW, running the "Try Ubuntu" from the Live CD it seems I won't be able to restart ? Because yesterday I've tried to restart but then it boot again from the Live CD.

Comment: @karma I’m not to sure what happens if you pass `fsck` the wrong file system, but you might want to try it without one; I believe it will auto detect if it can. And when you reboot your computer, depending on how you got to the live CD, you may need to either change your boot order back or press like “F12” or something (depending on your computer) to choose your boot volume.

Comment: If format is NTFS as it seems, better to run Windows repair like chkdsk The Linux dosfsck (fsck.fat) or the ntfsFix only does minor repairs and sets the chkdsk flag so Windows will run that anyway.

Comment: @oldfred Yeah probably so if OP has access to a Windows machine.

Comment: @PixelatedFish, thank you for your explanation. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @oldfred, the problem is when I tried chkdsk on Windows 10, it gave me a message something like _"chkdsk is not available for RAW drives"_

Comment: You need to see if you can restore or create the partition boot sector (BS) or PBR - partition boot sector. You want to get to this screen:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix Windows tools may be better, but do not know them. And then run chkdsk.